# Getting cookies from sub domain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a website, `www.example.com`, and would like to use a few cookies from this on another sub-domain: `www.abc.example.com`.

Can JavaScript read a cookie from a different subdomain? Meaning, if my
html page is running on `www.example.com`, can I get the cookies from this page to be used in `www.abc.example.com`?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to get these details from a simple search I believe. Anyway check this link and see you got what you need.

[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain)